# My MacBook Pro screen cracked and can't connect to external display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

My MacBook screen cracked (very minimal tiny crack) and at first it was showing something, a few minutes later the screen is completely black. Now, I didn't have an issue with that the first couple of days because I was using an external display so I didn't really mind the cracked black screen.

The problem is, one day I restarted the computer and now it won't connect to the external display and won't even get past the login screen (I was using voice over to login but after that nothing works, I'm assuming since voice over is not saying whats on screen).

Is there a way to fix the external display issue? I tried <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> to connect to it and I also tried resetting the NVRAM and SMC, but it didn't work.

Comment: **This is a physical issue and it needs to be taken in for service.**  There's no software fix that can overcome a physical failure and given you can't see what you're doing on screen, you wouldn't be able to implement it if there was.

Comment: You could use Screen Share to remote into the computer and view the settings, but I recommend Allan's advice to take it in for service.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slightly crazy idea to "give you eyes" on the Mac with the dead display. If you have easy access to a second Mac and the right cable to connect the two (e.g., Thunderbolt to Thunderbolt, USB-C to Thunderbolt, USB-C to USB-C, etc.), you could:

1. Connect the two Macs with said cable
2. Put your damaged MacBook Pro into Target Disk Mode by holding down its "T" key while you turn it on
3. Turn on the second Mac while holding down its Option key so you get to choose which partition to boot from
4. Choose the system volume of the broken MacBook Pro

This basically lets you use the intact second Mac to boot into the system that is installed on the MacBook Pro with the damaged screen. If there are indeed any software or hard drive issues with that first Mac that prevented you from logging in, you are now able to see and potentially address them.

For more details on Target Disk Mode, see [this](https://blog.macsales.com/41010-mac-os-101-how-to-boot-and-use-a-mac-in-target-disk-mode) guide.

Comment: That's amazing, I will try it when I have the time. Thanks!